# Ubuntu 16.04 - M.2 SSD doesn't display anything when using smartctl -a; unknown device type

Tags: ssd, nvme

All of my data on my M.2 SSD was deleted. It still works and data can be stored on it still. I wanted to check what the error was using smartctl, but when I type

```
smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
```

it says

```
/dev/nvme0n: Unable to detect device type
Please specify device type with the -d option.
```

I tried every device type (other than the usb options) and it wasn't able to give a proper output.

Comment: How about `sudo smartctl -a -d nvme /dev/nvme0n1`?

Comment: This is a [known limitation of 16.04's `smartmontools` package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/smartmontools/+bug/1616020).

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
sudo nvme list
sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
```

Comment: for readers - the `nvme` command is provided by the `nvme-cli` package